# how to enable Mongodb password Authentication?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i have an issue with  Authentication on mongodb in the config file ,
i also added

```
security:
    authorization: enabled
```

net:
port: 27017
bindIp: 0.0.0.0
and i added the user in admin table, but when i login with mongoose on nodejs no Authentication  are need , i use nodejs from my pc , mongodb is installed on ionos server

```
const url = 'mongodb://x.x.x.x.x:27017/';
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


mongoose.connect(url, (err) =>
{
    if(err)
    {
        console.log(err)
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('s')
    }
});
```

Comment: did you restart the service after editing the config file?

Comment: yup i tried   but that does not work

Comment: What do you mean by "added the user in admin table"? Did you insert in manually into the collection?

Comment: You can **always** connect to MongoDB, even without authentication. However, you cannot execute any command (apart from commands like `help` or `getDB()`, etc.) Thus `mongoose.connect()` does not raise an error.

Comment: yes i can even use getDB()